# Webpack code spliting with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting-async

I have module system with code splitting and lazy loading and dynamic import. Every module is a git repository and they importing in shell (the shell in which the modules are displayed). I want to deploy one module changes without rebuild. Does anyone can tell me the solution?

```
render (
  <Router>
    <Route
      path={'/moduleA'}
      component={() => <AsyncComponent module={() => import('./moduleA')} />}
    />
    <Route
      path={'/moduleB'}
      component={() => <AsyncComponent module={() => import('./moduleB')} />}
    />
  <Router>
);
```

When i go to the link '/moduleA' i loading 0.bundle.js
When i go to the link '/moduleB' i loading 1.bundle.js

Can i update `moduleA` without rebuild `moduleB` and shell?

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**! Please, in order to help can **you** provide some code?

Comment: @MatheusCuba sorry, i've added code and more information